# Algorithm for grouping colored boxes into squares

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, grouping, graph-algorithm

Assume a two-dimentional (`width` * `height`) array where each element is a colored box.

The count of boxes is `n`. The count of colors of all boxes is limited to a constant `c`, and `c <<< n`.

Now for a given `k`, find a way to group these boxes into larger squares, so that the count of all groups (squares) is closest to `k`, where the group item can be 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, ... boxes inside (so that they can form a square).

Within each group (square), the elements must all be the same color.
Single element squares are valid.
Squares cannot overlap.

Comment: Can the squares of same colored boxes overlap one another?

Comment: I assume " mostly approximately closed to k" means "closest to k"

Comment: r u looking 4 PSS http://www.squaring.net/sq/ss/s-pss.html ?

Comment: @ravenspoint, no, they cannot overlap. yes, it means "closest to k".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list all 2 by 2 squares of same colored boxes
while count of squares != k
  if count < k
      if possible to split largest square into smaller squares
          split
      else
          stop
  else 
      if possible to combine 4 small squares into one
          combine
      else
          stop
```

Comment: The part I cannot figure out is if a 4-box square can be combine into a 9-box square, in which case there are 1(larger)+5(smaller) boxes need to be considered. (and other non 4-same-size-square situations)

I'm not sure how to prove the result count is really the closest one to k.

Comment: "if a previous 4-box square can or cannot be combine into a 9-box square"  My proposed algorithm does not do this.  It combines 4 2 by 2 squares into 1 4 by 4 square.  This is possible if all 4 squares have the same color.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to prove ..." Proving optimality is an academic exercise.  I am interested in algos that provide reasonable results as quickly as possible so we can move on to the next problem.

Comment: Agreed. Practical effectiveness beats theoretical asymptotic bounds hands-down. (Except for homework, I suppose, but of course it were homework the OP wouldn’t be asking other people to do it for them.)